# Same jar (name + version) but different code by maven

Tags: spring-boot, maven, jar

I have run into a really frustrating bug.
I have a dependency in my pom.xml file -> `cd.connect.openapi.gensupport:openapi-generator-support:1.4`

I have two completely different project.
Each having its own pom.xml and both require this dependency.

Now one project works fine.

But in another project, while debugging, I found that this exact same dependency has buggy code in this project but not in another.

In this project, this jar has a class called `ApiClient.java`, which uses a static initialiser block to populate a `Map` for exception handling. This block uses some constants define in `Response.java`. But there are to constants which it uses in `ApiClient.java` and these 2 dont exist in `Response.java`. Hence when I run the code, I get error `NoSuchFieldError` and sometimes I get `NoClassDefFound`.

I tried reloading maven project, deleting .m2 folder so that the dependency gets downloaded again, but no luck.

Any suggestions are welcome.

**UPDATE**
`In Project that is not working`
`ApiClient.java` -> `cd.connect.openapi.gensupport:openapi-generator-support:1.4`

`Response.java` -> `javax.ws.rs.jsr-311 api`

`In Project that is working`
`ApiClient.java` -> `cd.connect.openapi.gensupport:openapi-generator-support:1.4`

`Response.java` -> `jakarta.ws.rs:jakarta.ws.rs-api:2.1.6`

**UPDATE-2**
In project that is working, jakarta jar is present and javax is not. So ApiClient is using jakarta.

But in project that is not working, both jakarta and javax are present and it is using javax, hence the problem.

So question boils down to how can I make it to use jakarta one.
Will try deleting javax one, hopefully it wont break anythin else.

Comment: Are you getting this error in project startup?

Comment: project starts successfully, when I hit a particular api which uses these dependencies, I get error

Comment: Response.java is present in dependency or it is part of your part?

Comment: Find how the dependency javax is imported using mvn dependency:tree and exclude it.

Comment: @LazarosChatzimichalakis correct, I did this to solve it.